# Update GPG SignWith in public repo prepared with reprepro

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, gnupg, reprepro

I have a public repo with 2 packages available. It's set up with `reprepro` and the thing is signed with a GPG key referenced by `SignWith` instruction in `public/conf/distributions`. Packages are added with  `reprepro -b public/ --ask-passphrase includedeb focal mypackage_amd64.deb`.

As the GPG key has expired, I need now to set a new one. So I did the following steps :

1. Generate a new GPG key `gpg --gen-key`.
2. Export the key with `gpg --armor --export 9B5BBD0820B7326B > repo.asc` withing the repo folder, so that the users will be able to `wget -q http://repo.example.com/repo.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -`
3. Changed every `SignWith` lines in `public/conf/distributions` to match that new gpg.

Now, when I get the files (http://repo.example.com/public/conf/distributions, http://repo.example.com/repo.asc), things seems right.

But `apt update` still complain :

> Err:1 http://repo.example.com/public focal InRelease
> The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 8320586119BDB444
> Author User.Name@example.com

That `8320586119BDB444` corrersponds to the previous GPG.
What is missing in this procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

Writing the question from beginning to end sometimes helps to figure out what was missing : )

I simply needed to re-generate repo files with the following commands :

```bsh
reprepro -b public/ --ask-passphrase export focal
reprepro -b public/ --ask-passphrase export bionic
```